# How to make about me layout using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create an about me page having this layout:

```
General Info.

Name:                 XYZ XYZ

Age:                  22

Gender:               Male


Contact Info.

Email:                xyz@yahoo.com

Phone number:         923XXXXXXXXX
```

It is like facebook about me page where items are on the left and their values are on the right at a specific distance but left aligned.
So what i want is that the values should be left-align at a specific distance from the items on the left.So is there any good way or a technique for such alignment instead of using different spacing for each of them ?

Comment: Use columns, it's how Bootstrap works. You should probably read the Bootstrap docs.

Comment: have you tried writing any markup by yourself?

Comment: Use a <table> or <dl> maybe...?

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it will be like below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">General Info</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">Name:</div><div class="col-sm-6">XYZ XYZ</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">Age:</div><div class="col-sm-6">22</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">Gender:</div><div class="col-sm-6">Male</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">Contact info</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">Email:</div><div class="col-sm-6">xyz@yahoo.com</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">Phone number:</div><div class="col-sm-6">923XXXXXXXXX</div>
</div>
```

Comment: well this is also a good way but i figured out tables are better way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @Raj while a table will work, are tables the right tool for the job?

Comment: @hungerstar i think you just asked the same thing I was about to ask. Bootstrap gives you so much flexibility, using table for this will be rendering bootstrap' styles somehow useless..

Comment: @CodingEnthusiast since i want the website to look good also in a mobile view, your code was not producing good result whereas a bootstrap table was providing a very nice layout even in a mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many data in your requested format using below code.

```
<html>
 <style type="text/css">
   #wrap {
     float:left;
     width:300px;
     margin:0 auto;
   }
   #left_col {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
   }
   #right_col {
    Float:left;
    width:100px;

  }
 </style>
 <div id="wrap">
     <div id="left_col">
          <p>Name:</p>
     </div>
     <div id="right_col">
          <p>XYZ XYZ</p>
     </div>
     <div id="wrap">
         <div id="left_col">
              <p>Age:</p>
         </div>
         <div id="right_col">
              <p>22</p>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: hey did you realise, you don't have a head or body tags in your code? And realise that you open divs and you don't close them . Pls fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need a visual practical result I think . So It would be better if you use a visual bootstrap designer .
[Layoutit](http://www.layoutit.com/en/)

This will help you to get quick result . For your project.

Comment: bootply too maybe? Jsfiddle too?